# Get the sum of absolutes of columns for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe and I want to sum the values of the columns I could do something like

```
import pandas as pd
studentdetails = {
       "studentname":["Ram","Sam","Scott","Ann","John","Bobo"],
       "mathantics" :[80,90,85,70,95,100],
       "science" :[85,95,80,90,75,100],
       "english" :[90,85,80,70,95,100]
              }
index_labels=['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6']
df = pd.DataFrame(studentdetails ,index=index_labels)
print(df)
df3 = df.sum()
print(df3)

col_list= ['studentname', 'mathantics', 'science']
print( df[col_list].sum())
```

How can I do something similar but instead of getting only the sum, getting the sum of *absolute values* (which in this particular case would be the same though) of some columns?
I tried `abs` in several way but it did not work

Edit:

```
   studentname  mathantics  science  english
r1         Ram          80       85       90
r2         Sam          90       95      -85
r3       Scott         -85       80       80
r4         Ann          70       90       70
r5        John          95      -75       95
r6        Bobo         100      100      100
```

Expected output

```
mathantics                        520
science                           525
english                           520
```

Edit2:
The `col_list` cannot include string value columns

Comment: Is possible add expected ouput? some values are negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need numeric columns for absolute values:

```
col_list = df.columns.difference(['studentname'])
df[col_list].abs().sum()

df.set_index('studentname').abs().sum()
df.select_dtypes(np.number).abs().sum()
```

Comment: `bad operand type for abs(): 'str'`

Comment: I found my error. col_list can not include studentname